# C++ getting rid of leading zeros

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to get array3[ARRAYSIZE] to print out with no leading zeros. How can i do this? INPUTS are 6
123456
7
1234567

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int ARRAYSIZE = 20;
void InitNumber(char array[ARRAYSIZE]);
int AddArrays(char array1[ARRAYSIZE], char array2[ARRAYSIZE],char arrayfinal[ARRAYSIZE]);
void OutputNumber(char array[ARRAYSIZE]);

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char array1[ARRAYSIZE], array2[ARRAYSIZE];
    char array3[ARRAYSIZE];
    bool number = false;

    cout << "Please enter your first number" << endl;
    InitNumber(array1);

    cout << endl << "Please enter your second number" << endl;
    InitNumber(array2);

    AddArrays(array1,array2,array3);

    OutputNumber(array3);
    int sum;
```

This is the problem area.
   Seems to print out á00000000000008308642 instead of 8308642. 
   Which loop is a better fit do while or a for loop.

```
    do {
        if(array3[ARRAYSIZE-i] != '0')      // heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp
            number = false;
        else
            number = true;
        sum = i++;
    } while(number == true);


    for(sum; sum <= ARRAYSIZE; sum++){          // Outputs all the terms
        cout << array3[ARRAYSIZE-sum];
    }


    return 0;
}

void InitNumber(char array[]){
    int numberofdigits, numbercount;
    int i;

    cout << "How many digits are in your number? ";
    cin >> numberofdigits;
    numbercount = numberofdigits;


    cout << "Please enter the digits in the number with the LEAST significant first: ";
    for(i = 0; i < numberofdigits; i++){    // Inputs the terms
        cin >> array[i];}


    for(numbercount; numbercount < ARRAYSIZE; numbercount++){
        array[numbercount] = '0';   // Inputs zeros into all other terms
    }

}

int AddArrays(char array1[],char array2[],char arrayfinal[]){
    int array1int, array2int, totalint, error =0, i = 0;
    char totalchar;
    for(ARRAYSIZE; ARRAYSIZE-i >= 0; i++){
        array1int = array1[i] - '0';
        array2int = array2[i] - '0';
        totalint = array1int + array2int + error;
        error = 0;
        if(totalint > 9){
            error = totalint/10;
            arrayfinal[i] = totalint%10;
        }

        else{
            arrayfinal[i] = totalint;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return totalint;
}

void OutputNumber(char array3[]){
    bool number;
    int i=0;
    for(ARRAYSIZE; ARRAYSIZE - i > 0; i++){
        array3[i] = array3[i] + '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is the print happening on? what is the significance of the value `8308642`

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: I have no idea why this program is so complicated, but a big issue is that spots in the array that aren't initialized will hold random values.  If you don't want to print 0s then change the loop to be `if (array3[ARRAYSIZE - sum] != '0') std::cout << array3[ARRAYSIZE - sum];`

Comment: the print statement is cout << array3[ARRAYSIZE-sum];

Comment: if i use`if (array3[ARRAYSIZE - sum] != '0') std::cout << array3[ARRAYSIZE - sum]; it wont print the 0 in 830642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loop (`i == 0`) you go out of array bounds by accessing `array3[ARRAYSIZE-i]`, that is `array3[ARRAYSIZE]`. You should start with `i = 1`, and also add  `&& i <= ARRAYSIZE` to the loop condition to get correct behavior if all digits are zeros.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/998a35d797fb72f2)

Comment: still doesnt remove leading zeros

Comment: @FreakinGhost check the demo I added